# Problem with adding imported function into exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

So basically I want this block:

```
const {someFunction} = require("/somePath");
exports.exportedFunction = (req, res) => { someFunction() }
```

to work like this block:

```
exports.exportedFunction = (req, res) => {
    const {someFunction} = require("/somePath");
    someFunction();
}
```

But without repeating the imports. How to prevent repeating imports into every single export? I want to have one import from which I can use the function into every export without importing exactly into exports. Is that even possible?

UPDATE: okay, there's small update. I have made a minimum requirement problem recreation and it looks like this:

```
//index.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("./router");

exports.exportableStuff = () => {
    return [1,2,3];
};
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("i am listening");
});

//router.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require("./controller");

router.get("/", controller.testModule);

module.exports = router;

//controller.js
const {exportableStuff} = require("./index");

exports.testModule = (req, res) => {
    console.log("it has been done");
    exportableStuff();
    res.send("<h1>hello, user</h1>");
}
```

UPDATE2: I actually managed to fix the closures myself. What I actually did to make this work is changing this:

```
const {exportableStuff} = require("./index");
```

Into:

```
const model = require("./index");
```

And call the function in my controller with model.exportableStuff().
Problem oficially solved, but if you have better idea, I'm all ears.

Comment: What is wrong with the first option?

Comment: when i export it from index.js as module.exports = { someFunction }, and then import it from router that imports the exportedFunction, log shows me that someFunction is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, I think you might want to do following thing?

```js
// index.js
module.exports = { someFunction }
```

```js
// router.js

// case1
const { someFunction } = require("./index.js")
someFunction() // it will work

// case2
const index = require("./index.js")
index.someFunction() // it will work
```

But, if you want to export your someFunction to another exports
then use new function, you need to do like this.

```js
// another.js
const { someFunction } = require("./index.js")
exports.exportedFunction = someFunction
```

```js
// router.js
const { exportedFunction } = require("./another.js")
exportedFunction() // it will work
```

Comment: So it looks like I got it the proper way. I'll check my code and then post and update, because it ends on the first import and then the router doesn't recognise required function from exports module from index.js. It's strange. Other installed modules work correctly but not this one.